# У меня не запускает apk. Само приложение создано react native expo. Выдаёт ошибку "couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so"

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

После создания билда через expo выдаёт ошибку:

2023-11-22 23:43:42.453 10010-10010 fb-UnpackingSoSource    pid-10010                            I  dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication/lib-main
2023-11-22 23:43:42.453 10010-10010 fb-UnpackingSoSource    pid-10010                            V  releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication/lib-main
2023-11-22 23:43:42.458 10010-10010 SoLoader                pid-10010                            V  libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication/lib-main
2023-11-22 23:43:42.459 10010-10010 SoLoader                pid-10010                            V  libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/~~iBpIDWhnTU5BfdbnDglfDw==/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication-LyiAksQPYxzmZ4VhLusTTQ==/lib/x86_64
2023-11-22 23:43:42.460 10010-10010 SoLoader                pid-10010                            E  couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication/lib-main flags = 1]
SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~iBpIDWhnTU5BfdbnDglfDw==/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication-LyiAksQPYxzmZ4VhLusTTQ==/lib/x86_64 flags = 0]
SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
Native lib dir: /data/app/~~iBpIDWhnTU5BfdbnDglfDw==/com.artemdegtyrov.archieapplication-LyiAksQPYxzmZ4VhLusTTQ==/lib/x86_64
result: 0